# Could I rephrase this question to make it better

Tags: discussion

Recently, I was trying to figure out if there were any big web frameworks or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872435/a-web-framework-for-dart?noredirect=1#comment44147250_27872435

Immediately, i received a down vote and the question was put on hold as off topic. It said:

```
"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Hobo Sapiens, minitech
```

I was simply trying to ask what was available. I would be like if I asked, hey, what kond of options do I have for writing web-apps in java, and people could have responded wit a number of options,  stating the strong points of each(SpringMVC, PLayframework, Struts)

I feel that a lot of the issue may have been how I worded it. I asked for a "popular" or "de facto" framework because, I don;t want answers like "here this is some piece of crap no one uses". I gave the back story because I wanted people to know where I was coming from.

Can I change the wording to fix the question? Is there something else I can do? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If you can somehow rephrase the question to not be asking for a list of software, it'd be better.  But i'm pretty sure that's not what you meant.  :P

Comment: Even if it would be possible to take out being opinion based and broad, this kind of questions are always inviting spam and here it is difficult to flag with good conscience as spam if the questions are already inviting these answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure others will provide great input, but for me it all comes down to your last sentence, which is your question. You write:

> Is there even a "popular" or "de facto" web framework for use with dart?

There is the big issue. The closing reason tells you exactly why: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow." When you ask for a recommendation of software, the responses are very likely going to be opinionated, and not very high quality. Though I haven't seen this written on the site, I'd also add that software recommendations aren't as useful for people reading the post in the future, as software changes so quickly. To give you an example, if a year ago you asked what software to use for Android development, many people would say Eclipse. Today, people will tell you almost unanimously to use Android Studio.

You may see very popular questions like this around the older parts of StackOverflow and wonder what the deal is. The guidelines for what kinds of questions can be posted have changed significantly since 4 years ago. Things that would have been fine then are off-topic now, such as software recommendations or opinion questions.

Now, you say in this meta-post

> I was simply trying to ask what was available. I would be like if I asked, hey, what kind of options do I have for writing web-apps in java

For asking for software recommendations and generally asking what your options are, there is the [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I don't think there is much you could do to make your question more on-topic for StackOverflow. The very premise of it doesn't necessarily fit with the [help page on asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).